# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint - Error output

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

When i put my script in phpmyadmin, it returns me back that error :

> ```
> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint,
>
> CREATE TABLE `t_cif` (   `idCif` int(11) NOT NULL,   `cifTitle`
> varchar(25) NOT NULL,   `cifDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
> `cifEval` float DEFAULT NULL,   `cifNbrEval` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
> `fkIdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,   `fkIdCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
> ```

my script code :

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Client :  localhost
-- Généré le :  Ven 09 Mars 2018 à 09:25
-- Version du serveur :  5.7.11
-- Version de PHP :  7.0.3
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mycifdb`;
CREATE DATABASE `mycifdb`;
USE `mycifdb`;
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de données :  `mycifdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `t_cif`
--

CREATE TABLE `t_cif` (
  `idCif` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cifTitle` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `cifDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cifEval` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cifNbrEval` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fkIdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkIdCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (idCif),
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkIdUser`) REFERENCES t_user(`idUser`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkIdCategory`) REFERENCES t_category(`idCategory`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `t_category`
--

CREATE TABLE `t_category` (
  `idCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`idCategory`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `t_user`
--

CREATE TABLE `t_user` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usePseudo` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `useDateEntry` date NOT NULL,
  `useNbrCif` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `useNbrEval` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usePassword` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `useEmail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: And i Tried so far with the followed syntax :

Comment: ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_grade_id FOREIGN KEY (grade_id) REFERENCES grades(id);

Comment: Sorry for the formatting confusion, hope it's alright now.

Comment: And it returns the same error, any idea ?

Comment: Your script starts with `create table t_cif`, tables `t_user` and `t_category` don't exist yet. Hence, you can't reference them.

Comment: Just a tip, when posting code, remove all not relevant stuff. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key in `t_cif` depends on `t_category` and `t_user`.

So `t_category` and `t_user` tables should be created before creating `t_cif` table.

Change the order of creating tables and check if its working.